# Yii activerecord field unserialize

Tags: php, mysql, serialization, yii

I have a yii model with the following fields (coming from an inherited database):

- id
- title
- series

Series is a php plain array serialized. I am looking for something (maybe in beforeFind() method ) to have this field unserialized first and be searched (an in_array() is enough). I've seen a solution that overrides findByAttribute() for an IP address but I can't understand how the function parameter works with the conditions.

Is there a similar example or a way to do the action?

Comment: you want to fetch series field first, then unserialize and then search using in_array ? can you paste some code which you tried ?

Comment: I am in the making. I saw [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/33422-how-to-use-cactiverecordbeforefind/page__p__160925#entry160925) but I am still new at yii activerecord methods... mostly on how the conditions parameter work in the `findByAttributes()`.

Comment: If an array is serialized inside database, then searching by this field would be hard, since the whole array is stored as a string

Comment: There may be a way to mix SQL queries with PHP find in array, but I would recommend you not to do it and I also wouldn't do the array in DB thing. You don't have to believe in total mvc to see the value of separating logic from data retrieval.

So why not have a series table which have a foreign_id to your table?

Comment: Actually, I can't change the database schema. Otherwise I would have made the simple parent-parent-child database changes and I wouldn't be on this mess. The other much less elegant way is to just get all these "items" unserialize them and do the matching in a `findAll()`, but I can't project how much the project will go.